Krull dimension of affinoid algebra
Let $K$ be a complete field w.r.t. a valuation, with residue field $k$. Let $A$ be an affinoid algebra over $K$ with respect to a valuation $V$ (in the sense of Tate; in the terminology of Berkovich, $A$ is a strictly affinoid algebra).
Suppose that $B \subseteq A$ is a dense finite type sub-$K$-algebra of $A$.
Is it true that the Krull dimension of $B$ and $A$ is the same? If so, could you please provide a reference?
I am mostly interested in the case that $V$ is discrete.

Notes:
$\dim B \geq \dim A$ holds in general, by the following argument.
For a seminormed ring $R$, $\tilde{R}$ denotes the topological residue ring of $R$ (power bounded elements modulo nilpotent elements). For an integral domain $S$, $Frac(S)$ denotes its fraction field.

$\tilde A \simeq \tilde B$. Hence $\tilde B$ is of finite type over $k$, and $\tilde B$ is an integral domain.
$B$ and $\tilde B$ are integral domains. By a version of Abhyankar's inequality: tr.deg.$Frac(\tilde B) /k \leq $ tr.deg.$Frac(B)/K$. As $B$ and $\tilde B$ are of finite type, this gives $\dim \tilde B \leq \dim B$.
For any reduced affinoid algebra we have $\dim \tilde A = \dim A$.

For certain 'nice' subalgebras the claim holds: e.g. if $T_d \to A$ is given by Noether normalization, then $K[x_1, \ldots, x_d] \subset T_d$ is a dense finite type sub-$K$-algebra of $T_d$ of Krull dimension $d$. Adding the finitely many generators of the $T_d$-module $A$ to $K[x_1, \ldots, x_d]$ gives such a 'nice' $B$.
The claim also holds if $\dim B = 1$.

Is there any reason to consider the Krull dimension of underlying rings of these topological rings, instead of Krull dimensions of associated valuative spectra $\operatorname{Spa}((-),(-)^+)$?

Dear @Z.M, I am actually starting with $B$, and I am mostly interested in the transcendence degree of its residue field, which I think is only really linked to the 'classical' Krull dimension. I just realized that for the cases that I care about the most, the completion happens to be affinoid. I phrased the question as above because it becomes a standalone question which experts might be able to answer.

In the Tate algebra in one variable $K{T}$, you can find an series $f(T)$ that is algebraically independent of $T$. Then $K[T,f(T)]$ provides a counter-example if I am not mistaken.
